# How to use geologica font in Send grid email template?

Tags: javascript, sendgrid, email-client, google-fonts, sendgrid-templates

I have to use Geologica font in my email template. I tried to link the font in the head section , in browser its displaying fine , but when I sent an sample email , the fonts are not applied.

I tried to convert the TTF font file to WOFF2 and encode it to base64 and use them as below:

```
 @font-face {
     font-family: 'Geologica';
     src: url(data:font/woff2;base64,YourBase64EncodedFontData) format('woff2');
     font-weight: 200; /* Specify the font weight */
     font-style: normal; /* Specify the font style */
 }
```

But Still , the fonts are not getting applied to email. Any suggestions or help on this would be appreciated.

EDIT ::
I have converted TTF file to WOFF now and to base64 and its working in the sendgrid editor as expected , but when i send email , in gmail the font are not getting applied.

Thanks